# Replace existent link in org-mode with org-stored link

Tags: org-mode, org-link, hyperlinks

Assume that I have a hyperlink to a file in org-mode

```
- [[file:~/Documents/one_document.txt][this is a link to one file]]
```

And then for some reason I want to update the linked file to some other file using `org-store-link`.

After using `C-c l`, I move back to my org file(pre-existent link), I hit `C-c C-l` and would hope that UP, DOWN or `M-p` would show me stored links--but it doesn't! Even if I delete the pre-existent link I never get to see the `*Org links*` buffer.

From reading [the documentation](https://orgmode.org/guide/Hyperlinks.html) it seems that I should be able to see the stored links. If so, does anyone knows why I can't? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `org-insert-link` (<kbd>C-c C-l</kbd>) on an existing link does *not* use `org-stored-links`, as [you can see in its source](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/ff8683aa35ef2aeb8964b96bf6de66d88e13a31c/lisp/ol.el#L1767-L1773):

```lisp
;; Answers note: code taken from `org-insert-link' on commit ff8683aa35
    ...
    (cond
     (link-location)              ; specified by arg, just use it.
     ((org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re 1)
      ;; We do have a link at point, and we are going to edit it.
      (setq remove (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
      (setq desc (when (match-end 2) (match-string-no-properties 2)))
      (setq link (read-string "Link: "
                  (org-link-unescape
                   (match-string-no-properties 1)))))
    ...
```

Instead `org-insert-link` only uses `read-string` with your current link. However, we can use an advice to modify both `org-stored-links` as well as the current link:

```lisp
(defun remove-link-and-mark-description (&rest args)
  "Removes the link at point and marks the description.

The previous link gets stored into `org-stored-links'. ARGS is unused"
  (cond
   ((org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re 1)
    (let* ((link (match-string-no-properties 1))
           (desc (if (match-end 2) (match-string-no-properties 2) link))
           (deactivate-mark))
      (push (list (org-link-unescape link) desc) org-stored-links)
      (replace-match desc)
      (push-mark (match-beginning 0) t t)))
   (t nil)))

(advice-add 'org-insert-link :before #'remove-link-and-mark-description)
```

However, the code above is merely a proof of concept. There are some bugs, e.g. the stored link doesn't follow Org's usual `file:...` format if used on files, and `push` should probably get replaced by `add-to-list`.

Comment: I am surprised that this is not implemented by default.  Your solution returned an error, so it might have to be slightly changed. I will give feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: @Ajned Which `emacs-version` and `org-version` do you use?

Comment: Indeed, I should have stated that right at the beginning. Emacs v26.3, Org mode v9.4. and the error is `"Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil "Removes the link at point and marks the description. The previous link gets stored into `org-stored-links'." (cond ((org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re 1) (let* ((link (match-string-no-properties 1)) (desc (if (match-end 2) (match-string-no-properties 2) link)) (deactivate-mark)) (setq org-stored-links (cons (list (org-link-unescape link) desc) org-stored-links)) (replace-match desc) (push-mark (match-beginning 0) t t))) (t nil))), 1"`

Comment: I can reproduce the error with Emacs v26.3, Org mode v9.1. It works fine on Emacs 27.1. There might have been some changes with `advice-add`. I'll check the NEWS.

Comment: @Ajned I'm not entirely sure why it's necessary in Emacs 26.3, but apparently `remove-link-and-mark-description` must take an argument in 26.3. `&rest args` makes sure that it works in both 26.3 and 27.1.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! There is only one small detail (for whoever might use your solution). If for some reason the update is cancelled, for example via `C-g` the link disappears. Minor thing, but just thought worth mentioning.